# How to run vagrant in Windows which is running in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: windows, macos, vagrant, virtual

I'm running vagrant inside Windows 7.1 which is running in VMWare Fusion on a MacBook Pro (2014 model.)

The problem is that I believe the "vagrant up" needs the VT extensions to be enabled so that I can use ssh to connect to the instance.

I have tried turning this on in VMWare Fusion's settings (obviously I can't do this in the BIOS because Windows in running in a virtual machine) but I get other errors (such as failed startup and messages saying that it is running in gurumaintenance mode(?))

How can I configure my VM Ware Windows 7.1 to let me run vagrant in Windows?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't run Vagrant natively on your Mac here?

Comment: I need it to be visible to the sites I have running under the VM Windows' IIS

Comment: I have now setup vagrant in a Mac-hosted virtualbox. What I need now is to have the applications hosted by virtualbox on the mac addressable from the VMWare Fusion-hosted Windows 7.1